# Can I query for and retrieve members of a collection property in RavenDB using full text search?

Tags: full-text-search, nested, ravendb

I'm using the term "child documents" loosely relating to objects stored in a collection property. Given those two classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to query for Bars which have the term "roses" in either their Name or Description properties. Please note that Bars are stored within Foo.

This is a two fold question:

1. Can a query be used over a collection of type Foo to return Bars ("child document")? I want to get a collection of Bars which have "roses" in their Name, other Bars should be skipped. I don't want Foos (aggregate root) returned.
2. If so, how to do it with full text search?

Regarding #1, I know something like that is impossible in MongoDB, where I would either have to store Foo and Bar separately or query for Foos where any of their Bars has "roses" in the Name and then do something about it on the client. But RavenDB has Live Projections / TransformResults, so I thought it would be possible perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store a copy of each Bar in field storage with the index, so yes - it can be done.  But you should make sure you understand the impact of doing this.

Normally when you query from raven, the index is only used to determine which documents get sent back.  The documents themselves don't come from the index, but from the document store.  The document store has ACID guarantees - meaning you will always get the most current copy of the document regardless of the state of the index.  If you project from index entries or index field storage, then the values you get back are as stale as the index itself.

Say you are constantly updating the Bars, and you search before the index has caught up to your last update.  You could get back a Bar that has old data.  Therefore, you need to weigh in the potential staleness of data into your results, possibly using one of the `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOf...` customizations - which will slow the speed your search results return if you have lots of writes going on.

```cs
public class Foos_BarsByName
    : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Foo, Foos_BarsByName.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Bar Bar { get; set; }
    }

    public Foos_BarsByName()
    {
        Map = foos => from foo in foos
                      from bar in foo.Bars
                      select new
                      {
                          bar.Name,
                          Bar = bar
                      };

        Index(x => x.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(x => x.Bar, FieldIndexing.No);
        Store(x => x.Bar, FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}

var results = session.Query<Foos_BarsByName.Result, Foos_BarsByName>()
                     .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow())
                     .Search(x => x.Name, "roses")
                     .Select(x => x.Bar);
```

Another way to handle it might be to let all Foos come back, and then pull out the Bars you are interested in on the client side.  At least then, everything comes from the document store:

```cs
public class Foos_BarsByName
    : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Foo, Foos_BarsByName.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public Foos_BarsByName()
    {
        Map = foos => from foo in foos
                      from bar in foo.Bars
                      select new
                      {
                          bar.Name
                      };

        Index(x => x.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}

var results = session.Query<Foos_BarsByName.Result, Foos_BarsByName>()
                     .Search(x => x.Name, "roses")
                     .As<Foo>()
                     .AsEnumerable()
                     .SelectMany(x => x.Bars)
                     .Where(x => x.Name.IndexOf("roses",
                                     StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                     != -1)
```

`.AsEnumerable()` will force the linq-to-raven query to execute, making everything that follows happen in linq-to-objects on the client side.

Of course, if you are doing a more advanced search than can be expressed with c# string functions, then you won't be able to take this second approach.

Comment: I don't think I need to care about stale results for what I need to do. It's OK if the users wait a bit for their additions/edits to make it to the search results. I will make sure to display a notification.

It turns out I actually needed to build a composite structure having some fields from Foo and some from Bar, but the approach is the same. You helped me a lot, Matt, and I thank you for that!